# Incorrect use of ddply to summarise data in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a problem performing a fairly simple ddply operation: I have the following dataframe.

```
+----------+----------+
| Expenses | Category |
+----------+----------+
|      735 |        1 |
|      992 |        2 |
|      943 |        1 |
|      995 |        3 |
|      914 |        3 |
|      935 |        1 |
|      956 |        3 |
|      946 |        2 |
|      978 |        1 |
|      924 |        1 |
+----------+----------+
```

I am trying to calculate the N and mean of expenses for each category, by executing the following:

```
ddply(df, .(Category), summarise, N = length(df$Expenses), mean = mean(df$Expenses))
```

However i get:

```
  Category  N  mean
1        1 10 931.8
2        2 10 931.8
3        3 10 931.8
```

Could you help figuring out what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the df's `dput`:

```
structure(list(Expenses = c(735, 992, 943, 995, 914, 935, 956, 
946, 978, 924), Category = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Expenses", "Category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: You don't need `df$` inside ddply, so try `ddply(df, .(Category), summarise, N = length(Expenses), mean = mean(Expenses))`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I completely missed the original question you're pointing me to though, should look better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr);

grouped_df    <- group_by(df, Category);
summarized_df <- summarize(grouped_df, N    = n(),
                                       mean = mean(Expenses));
summarized_df;
```